# "Как" - сравнение или "в качестве" (см.)?

Tags: оборот-с-как

Нужна ли запятая после "мозгу"?

*Он словно подключился к мозгу как к компьютеру.*

Здесь "в качестве" или "сравнение"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Он словно подключился **к мозгу**, **как к компьютеру**.*

Это сравнительный оборот, который нужно обособить.

**При повторе падежных форм** сравнительный оборот по значению близок с придаточному сравнительному предложению: *Он словно подключился к мозгу, как (подключаются) к компьютеру.*

Сравнить: *Он использует мозг **как компьютер**.* Здесь значение "в качестве", нет обособления.